# How can I turn off camera video background in Unity ARKit

Tags: unity-game-engine, arkit

I'm trying to build a "lights-off" feature in my ARKit app, where I basically turn off the camera video background and only show my 3D content, sort of like VR.

Could someone please help me figure out how to turn off the the video background. I can see that a material called YuVMaterial is being used to render the camera texture but setting that to single color actually covers the entire screen and doesn't show my 3D content either.

Comment: How about creating a big cube?

Comment: Oh interesting. I didn't think of that. Could be a neat hack. Let me try it and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unity, you can switch between cameras while using ARKit. The main camera has a run time spherical video applied to it, so it's not actually your device camera, but a rendering of what the device camera sees. By switching cameras, you can effectively "turn off" the background video image, but still take advantage of the ARKit properties. Have fun.

Comment: That works! I also found another solution. Basically, set UnityARVideo to inactive and set the Camera clear flags to "Solid Color" - black.

Answer (score 1):

You can uncheck the UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation.ARCameraBackground component under the main AR camera, it will just render a black background.